# Using regex in tuple filter

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a list of tuples:

```
lst = [('4', 'None', '--'), ('5', 'None', '--'), ('7', 'PSC3', 'SAD1510034G'), ('8', 'SMC', 'SAD164400FV')]
```

I want to filter all out the tuples that have 'None' in them. The following expression with hardcoded values works:

```
>>> list(filter(('4','None','--').__ne__,lst))
[('5', 'None', '--'), ('7', 'PSC3', 'SAD1510034G'), ('8', 'SMC', 'SAD164400FV')]
```

What I can't figure out is how to use a regex/wildcard in the filter expression, something like:

```
list(filter(('*','None','--').__ne__,lst))
```

Maybe that's not possible.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2):

You can use a membership check instead of a regex, like so:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: 'None' not in x, lst))
[('7', 'PSC3', 'SAD1510034G'), ('8', 'SMC', 'SAD164400FV')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter based on the second value in the tuple not being `None`:

```py
lst = [('4', 'None', '--'), ('5', 'None', '--'), ('7', 'PSC3', 'SAD1510034G'), ('8', 'SMC', 'SAD164400FV')]
list(filter(lambda t:t[1] != 'None', lst))
```

Output:

```py
[
 ('7', 'PSC3', 'SAD1510034G'),
 ('8', 'SMC', 'SAD164400FV')
]
```